# JS - How to avoid long if else statement when condition is based on Object's property availability

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement

Given a configuration object my function should do one of several data processing.

For example, giving the following config:

```
{
  name:"my data"
}
```

the processed results would be:

```
[{
   name:"my data",
   data:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
}]
```

If the config is:

```
{
   name:"my data",
   dimension: "group_name"
}
```

Then the results, is grouped by the dimension and the output is:

```
[
 {
   name:"group 1",
   data:[0.5,0.5]
 },
 {
   name:"group 2",
   data:[1,1]
 },
 {
   name:"group 3",
   data:[2,2]
 }
// And so on ...
]
```

There are several configurations available, and I want to avoid a long **if else / switch case** statement that checks the existence of the required object properties.

What is a more elegant alternative?

Comment: You're going to have to check your configuration object at some point with an `if` ...

Comment: Write a helper function that does it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript test for existence of nested object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key)

Answer (score 0):

you could create a function mapping object like so:

```
const mapping = {
  "name":()=>{
    //process the data according to name configuration
  },
  "dimension_name":()=>{
    //process the data according to name and dimension configuration
  }
};
```

then on your code you can build the appropriate key by filtering properties not related to your logic like so:

```
const properties = ["dimension","name"];
const selectedProcess = Object.keys(confObject).filter((key) => {
  return properties.indexOf(key) !== -1;
}).sort().join("_");
```

that will return "**name**" when only **name** property was present on the config, and **dimension_name** when both properties exists.

Then you can just call the right method according to that key, like so:

```
mapping[selectedProcess]();
```

you can add as many properties as you like, just remember to update the properties array.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!